# Emacs: How to capitalize all keywords (example in SQL)

Tags: sql, emacs

For example, I have the following example SQL document in `SQL[ANSI]` mode:

```
create table title_price as 
select title, price 
from frumble 
group by title, price 
order by title;

select *, count(*) 
from frumble 
group by title, price 
order by title;
```

Any ideas on how to capitalize the keywords, like `select`, `from`, `group`, `by`, `table`, `as`, etc? 
They are already shown in blue font in my editor.

Comment: See also [Automatically formatting SQL code](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13214).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my attempt at solution (assuming you want to upcase `MySQL` keywords)

```lisp
(defun point-in-comment ()
  (let ((syn (syntax-ppss)))
    (and (nth 8 syn)
         (not (nth 3 syn)))))

(defun my-capitalize-all-mysql-keywords ()
  (interactive)
  (require 'sql)
  (save-excursion
    (dolist (keywords sql-mode-mysql-font-lock-keywords) 
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward (car keywords) nil t)
        (unless (point-in-comment)
          (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
          (upcase-word 1))))))
```

After evaluating this function, just do <kbd>M-x</kbd>`my-capitalize-all-mysql-keywords`<kbd>RET</kbd>. The advantage of this solution is that it picks up the keywords from Emacs `sql-mode`, you do not need to specify them.

Also I assumed you meant you wanted to `upcase` the words

Comment: Is there a way to have this function ignore the "keywords" that are in commented out text?

Comment: @Lucas, I have updated the answer should be better now

Comment: I have tried it out, and it is working great! The ONLY other downside is when I name an attribute using a keyword (ie "first", "last", or "date") - then the function will incorrectly capitalize the attribute (because it thinks my attribute name is a keyword).

Answer (score 7):

I've written [`sql-upcase.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlUpcase) for upper-casing keywords and function names in `sql-mode` and/or `sql-interative-mode`.

It provides `sql-upcase-region` and `sql-upcase-buffer` commands for processing pre-existing SQL, but differs significantly from the other solutions in that it also provides a `sql-upcase-mode` minor mode which processes text automatically as it is inserted. This means (a) that SQL keywords are upcased as you type them, and (b) that you can paste SQL into a `sql-mode` buffer, and *all* of the keywords will automatically be upcased.

This will hopefully Just Work for all the SQL products supported by Emacs, as it uses the keyword regexps defined for the buffer's `sql-product`. This was initially inspired by the use of font-lock keywords in Douglas La Rocca's function for upper-casing all PostgreSQL keywords in a buffer, which can be found on the [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlMode) (which also bears similarities to the method used in user2053036's accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22094733/324105) here).

Follow the link for more details.

Comment: n.b. This will likely end up on GNU ELPA, but lives on the Emacs Wiki for now.

Answer (score 2):

Try out this function:

```
(defun capitalize-sql-in-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((regex
         (format
          "\\_<%s\\_>" 
          (regexp-opt
           '("create" "table" "select"
             "from" "group by" "order by" "as"
             "count")))))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward regex nil t)
      (let ((beg (match-beginning 0))
            (end (match-end 0))
            (str (match-string 0)))
        (delete-region beg end)
        (insert (upcase str))))))
```

You can add more keywords as needed, I'm not really proficient in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `M-x replace-regexp`.
Just try these commands.

```
ESC M-<
M-x replace-regexp RET
\(select\|from\|group\|by\|table\|as\) RET
\,(capitalize \1) RET
```

Input:

```
create table title_price as 
select title, price 
from frumble 
group by title, price 
order by title;

select *, count(*) 
from frumble 
group by title, price 
order by title;
```

output:

```
create Table title_price As 
Select title, price 
From frumble 
Group By title, price 
order By title;

Select *, count(*) 
From frumble 
Group By title, price 
order By title;
```

Answer (score 2):

[sqlup-mode](https://github.com/Trevoke/sqlup-mode.el) capitalizes keywords as you type them, and provides a function to capitalize keywords in the selected region.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hacky way that I use for capitalizing keywords in `sql-interactive-mode` buffers:

```
(defun upcase-last-keyword ()
  (when (and (= last-input-event ? )
             (save-excursion
               (backward-char 2)
               (eq (face-at-point) 'font-lock-keyword-face)))
    (upcase-word -1)))
(add-hook 'sql-interactive-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (make-local-variable 'post-self-insert-hook)
            (add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'upcase-last-keyword))))
```